# Israeli bank account statement terminology

Tags: bank-account, israel

I have an account with Bank Leumi in Israel. Said bank provides me with account statements that look like this:

```
Date Description ReferenceNumber Debit
01/03/19 DIRECT TRANS 1FEE 1 1.65
01/03/19 MIN COM SUPPLEMENT 27594 3.85
```

Could please someone explain what "direct trans 1fee" and "min com supplement" is? I tried asking their support, yet I don't speak Hebrew well and they seem to have a similar issue with English.

Comment: Call customer support again.  Ask for someone who speaks fluent English fluent.  They're pretty much bilingual in Israel, more so in large businesses that deal internationally (like a bank).

Comment: Twenty years ago all the major banks had branches specializing in foreigners' accounts. As the use of non-USA banks by US citizens evading taxes became more difficult, I see Bank Leumi has only one left, at 43 Allenby St.,
Tel Aviv. Phone is 972-76-868-0399. You should find a fluent English speaker there. Our experience was that Israeli banks have multiple fees.